# USB-C to DisplayPort Cable Problem

Tags: usb, displayport, imac-pro

I bought [this](https://aliexpress.com/item/TOFOCO-USB-C-to-DisplayPort-Cable-4K-60Hz-USB-3-1-Type-C-Thunderbolt-3/32826982253.html) USB-C to DisplayPort cable in order to connect my iMac Pro to [this](http://www.dell.com/ed/business/p/dell-p2314h/pd) monitor. However, the cable does not work, the iMac does not even recognize the monitor. I tried with a non-Apple laptop of a colleague and also with another monitor (same model) and still nothing.

Is the cable broken or does the monitor not support this kind of connection? Thanks.

Comment: Two different computers, but same cable and monitor and the problem still exists?  It's a safe bet that one of those two (cable/monitor) is not functioning.  I would try a *different* cable at this point since it's the easiest thing to test. If the new cable still doesn't work with either your Mac or colleague's computer; your display is likely the problem.

Comment: @Allan I did try with another monitor (same model). I updated the question. The thing is that it is an old-ish monitor, could it be a compatibility issue? I do not have another cable..